# Can the power of an attack be reduced below two?

Tags: illuminati

When you are attacking in Illuminati and you're in the phase where players are spending Megabucks to aid or hinder the attack, is there a limit to how money can be spent to reduce the power of the attack?

Let's say that, after all the modifiers for alignment, the power of my attack is 8. Can another player reduce the power to -2 by spending 10 Megabucks? If so, do I actually get to roll the dice, or does the attack not take place at all? Or are they limited to spending 6, which gives me at least a miniscule chance to succeed on the attack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no limits.

To succeed you need to roll the target number or less on two dice.  If the target number has been reduced to 1 (or less) then the roll is moot.

This isn't stated explicitly in the [rules](http://www.sjgames.com/illuminati/img/illuminati_rules.pdf), but more importantly there are no limits placed on spending.  It is alluded to though, on page 5 in the "Spending money to Attack " section:

> For instance, if an attacker uses enough money
>   and power to exceed the target’s resistance by 20, the
>   defender would have to spend 20 MB to get the attacking
>   roll back down to zero again!

Comment: Thanks. We had an issue come up in a game where somebody still tried to roll when it was -13 and then played the Assassination plot card, thinking that 2 was an automatic success.